# How to sum up total javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i sum up the total from my room price and for the add on price
My code for addons and room booking js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".bkng").on("click",function(event) {
              event.preventDefault();

            var id = $(this).data('room-id');
          name = $(this).data('name');
        price = $(this).data('price');
                if(id != '')

                {
                    $.ajax(
                {
                    type:"POST",
                    url : "Pages/ajax",
                    data:{id:id,
                        name:name,
                        price:price},


                    success:function(data)
                    {
                        console.dir(data);
                        if (data) {


                        var item = $('<li data-itemprice="'+price+'">'+name+' : '+price+'</li>');
                            $("#test1").html(item);
Total();
```

Same for my addon js with its same data-itemprice

```
var item = $('<li data-itemprice="'+price+'">'+name+' : '+price+'</li>');
                            $("#test4").append(item);
Total();
```

my function for my total & how can i call the function to my html page?

```
function Total() {

           var total = 0;
         $('li').each(function(index,object){

         total = total + Number($(object).data('itemprice'))

   });

         $("#test2").html("Total:" + total);

    }
```

Here is the button html of my room and add ons
Rooms:

```
<button data-name = "Single Room" data-price = "2750" class="bkng bkn-room trans_200" data-room-id ="1">BOOK NOW</button>
```

AddOns:

```
<button data-name = "Airport Transfer" data-price = "4300"  class="addons addon-btn trans_200" data-addon-id ="1">ADD TO MY STAY</button>
```

My html for the total price display

```
<h3 class = "your-stay" id = "test2">Total:<span></span></h3>
```

Comment: When you click Addon button then simply add onclick event on this button or call your javascript function ```CalculateTotal()``` in onclick button.

Comment: can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

Call this calculate total function after implementing the li tag from success of ajax return.

Comment: can you give me an example of how to call a function after implementing my li tag?

Comment: success:function(data)
                    {
                        console.dir(data);
                        if (data) {


                        var item = $('<li data-itemprice="'+price+'">'+name+' : '+price+'</li>');
                            $("#test1").html(item);

CalculateTotal();
}
},

Comment: it says my CalculateTotal is not defined any idea why?

Comment: where you declare the CalculateTotal()? isn't it in same js file?

Comment: its ok now i move them on the same js but it does not display the total price any idea why?

Comment: your selection of element tag inside CalculateTotal have some issues. So far i have seen. Please inspect element in browser and see the correct element tag to pick the price for total sum.

Comment: it does not show the correct element tag in the inspect element

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            var total = 0
            $('li').each(function (index, object) {
                total = total + Number($(object).data('itemprice'))
            });
            $("span").html("Total:-" + total);
        });
        function Total()
        {
            var total = 0
            $('li').each(function (index, object) {
                total = total + Number($(object).data('itemprice'))
            });
            $("span").html("Total:-" + total);
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
        <li data-itemprice='200'>
            Room 1
        </li>
        <li data-itemprice='200'>
            Room2
        </li>
    </ul>
    <span> Total</span>
    <button onclick="Total()">Calculate</button>
```

There are many way to use your javascript function like this

```
$("#button").click( function()
       {
         CalculateTotal();
       }
    );
```

Comment: it does not display the total price any idea why?

Comment: now then you have to check your CalculateTotal(); function. This function is working properly or not.

Comment: I have edit my answer and add running function but you can see i have also add document. ready so as per your requirements you can use which one is your requirements.

Comment: do i need to create a <ul> for me to display the total output? because im using a div id to display the total price

Comment: i tried doing this but the display on total was always this "Total:NaN" can you please tell me why is that the output?

Comment: @JedJamir check number and every value in console or debug the java script or share here so i can check

Comment: i've edited my post can you please take a look at it? its now my latest code and i've called my function after i appended an item which is the name and the price of the data

Comment: NaN means you trying to convert string which is not valid for Number that mean your data-itemprice is not a number so please check. and let me know

Comment: can you pinpoint the problem in my code? i tried doing this  total =  Number($(object).data('itemprice')) but it only displays the price of the data not the total if i add it back the original  total = total + Number($(object).data('itemprice')) it errors NaN in my total

Comment: try this ```Number($(object).attr('data-itemprice'))``` and add your price in consol.log to check this is getting number or not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203517/discussion-between-dharmeshsharma-and-jed-jamir).

Comment: i tried to console.log the total and it says NaN 2750. the 2750 is the price of the 1 data it does not compute the total like if i click 2 addons it displays the price of each addons not  the total do you have idea why?